How to install Python 3.8.7 using Pip (or easy_install) only in a virtualenv
I have created a virtualenv and want to install python v.3.8.7 using either pip or easy_install tools without affecting the python version installed on the system which Python 2.7.
I tried using:
pip install python3 --upgrade #in the virtual environment

But the error states that I need to upgrade Python 2.8 which is the main Python used on my machine (not the virtualenv)
 DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3 (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3



python -m pip3 install --upgrade pip

I tried to upgrade pip only on virualenv: but same error:
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (20.3.4)

How to install Python 3.8.7 in a virtual environment using either pip or easy_install ?

I think you got that backwards. You create a virtual environment with the Python version you want to use in it. Install 3.8.7 alongside your system version. pip is used to install Python packages, not Python itself.

You cannot install Python using pip. You cannot install Python directly into a virtualenv. First you need to install it globally, then recreate the virtualenv. "Globally" doesn't mean "to the OS"; you can install it to your home directory.

You could use pyenv to install an user-local version of Python 3.8.7, then use it to create the virtualenv.

pyenv, asdf, conda, deadsnakes…

none of these work, the question is how to install Python using tools except apt get and pyenv?

conda IMO is the most reliable way. I use it all the time to install all versions of Python from 2.7 to 3.12.

how to install conda with only pip?

Why limit yourself with "only pip"? pip is not a full-blown package manager. With a few minor exception pip can only install Python libraries. Why not install conda properly? Install miniconda and configure conda-forge channel. Or install miniforge, it uses conda-forge channel by default.

I think the python3.8.7  is not installed in your system? I mean the python file install in their website, not the pip install in your env.
You may visit https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-387/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
